# stacktrace E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception, leaderboard

i am developing a android app with firebase leaderboard, it working well, but crash when i click on **leaderboard**, 
here is stack trace logs,
 i am getting 2 error:

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
12-02 01:05:53.969 3508-3508/com.example.myapp E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                            at com.example.myapp.activity.LeaderboardActivity$4.onChildAdded(LeaderboardActivity.java:167)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaer.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
12-02 01:05:54.215 3508-3508/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 3508
                                                                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                         at com.examle.myapp.activity.LeaderboardActivity$4.onChildAdded(LeaderboardActivity.java:167)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaer.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

both blue lines indicate error on this line in leaderboardactivity.java

```
if (leaderboards.get(1).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(displayName)) {
```

here is code snippet from leaderboardactivity.java

```
private void getLeaderboard() {

        databaseLeaderboard.orderByChild("score").limitToLast((int) totalValue).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                Leaderboard leaderboard = dataSnapshot.getValue(Leaderboard.class);
                leaderboards.add(leaderboard);

                if (leaderboards.size() >= (int) totalValue) {
                    Collections.reverse(leaderboards);
                    leaderboardAdapterNew.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                if (leaderboards.size() == totalValue) {


                    if (leaderboards.get(0).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(displayName)) {
                        txtUname1.setText("Me");
                    } else {
                        txtUname1.setText(leaderboards.get(0).getName());
                    }
                    if (leaderboards.get(1).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(displayName)) {
                        txtUname2.setText("Me");
                    } else {
                        txtUname2.setText(leaderboards.get(1).getName());
                    }
                    if (leaderboards.get(2).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(displayName)) {
                        txtUname3.setText("Me");
                    } else {
                        txtUname3.setText(leaderboards.get(2).getName());
                    }
```

can someone tell me where is my fault?

Comment: you leaderboard.get(1) has nothing. that's why you're getting this error

Comment: You're accessing index 1 in an array that only holds 1 item (so the highest legal index is 0)

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: I do not think the above code is accusing for the crash. Can you share your adapter ?LeaderboardActivity.java line no. 167?

Comment: Next time please try to properly format your code, it'll help other guys to answer your question.

Comment: diegoveloper solved my issue. anyway line no. 167-  `if (leaderboards.get(1).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(displayName)) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist:

Change this :

```
if (leaderboards.size() == totalValue) {
```

To this:

```
if (leaderboards.size() == totalValue && totalValue > 2) {
```

Comment: thanks. bro, for doing my homework.  actually i am not a developer, and  i bought this project from codecanyon, now author not responding my messages, so at last after 3 day i asked it on stackoverflow. 
thankyou